# print every 5 images in customTableView cell in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I have an array of size 50 and I was wondering if there is a way I can print every 5 image from my array to each cell? For example, cell 1 will have images from 0 - 4, cell 2: 5 - 9 ...

Thanks for the help

EDIT: This is for iOS not for OSX

Comment: Are you asking about iOS or OS X?

Comment: iOS. Thanks for reminding me to clarify that

Comment: For iOS, you may be better of with `UIStackView`

Answer (score 0):

If you are determined to use `UItableView` then you need to:

1. Make a cell prototype in storyboard, add 5 ImageViews to the cell in the position you would like them to be
2. Make a class extending `UITableViewCell`, set it in storyboard as the class for the prototype cell, drang-and-drop the ImageViews as outlets to that class
3. In the class you want to use it, you would want something like this:

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> MyCustomTablleCellWithFiveImagesInIt {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyReusableCellID", forIndexPath: indexPath)

       cell.image1 = datasource[indexPath.row * 5 + 0] 
       cell.image2 = datasource[indexPath.row * 5 + 1] 
       cell.image3 = datasource[indexPath.row * 5 + 2] 
       cell.image4 = datasource[indexPath.row * 5 + 3] 
       cell.image5 = datasource[indexPath.row * 5 + 4] 

       return cell
   }
   ```

and do not forget to

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return datasource.count/5
}
```

But I would recommend you rather use `UICollectionView`